# Can activeX controls be global?

Tags: vba, excel

Is any possible to create global activeX control? On this case I have textbox on "sample" sheet. On another sheet i want to add text, to this textbox. I tried initiate this control on module:

```
Public Sub log()
    'code
End Sub
```

but...

[image: error]

The pseudocode is like that

```
Sheet1 (on this sheet I have control) 
Sheet2    log.TEXT = "something"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have on `"sample"` sheet *ActiveX* textbox control with name `"Log"`.
To change its text anywhere in code just use following line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sample").OLEObjects("Log").Object.Text = "Something"
```